# Why ask both for CV and publication list?

Tags: job-search, cv, funding

Some academic job posts and grant applications require submitting both a CV and a publication list. I would have thought that it is a standard to put the publication list in the CV, hence it is not necessary to have the publication list again. What is the purpose of requiring both of them?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

On mathjobs, my workflow when glancing through files from candidates is to look at the publication list instead of the CV.  This is for two main reasons:

1. CVs typically frontload a bunch of information which I already have from the mathjobs cover sheet (education, postdoc, advisors, etc).
2. CVs are longer than one page, so finding the publications takes some time.  Publication lists have the info I'm looking for right at the beginning.

Comment: Do you really find looking at a raw publication list all that helpful?  Anyways, in the particular case of mathjobs, I think the answer is actually that "asking for a publication list is the default when you set up a position and no one bothers to uncheck the box."

Comment: @BenWebster: I like that it's information dense. With hundreds of applications I like something that at a glance quickly says whether the file is worth looking at in depth.

Answer (score 6):

A CV is generally a short account of your employment history and skills, often squeezed (or stretched) into 4 pages.

Publication lists can span many many pages. 100 complete publication entries (including technical reports and invited contributions etc etc) could easily span 10 pages.

In short, CV contains the summary from a global perspective, whereas the publication list contains all details of one particular aspect of a person.

Comment: My understanding is that a CV is supposed to be comprehensive, not short.  When e.g. grant agencies want a much shorter cv they ask for a **biographical sketch** (two pages).

Answer (score 0):

CV should be short (never more than 2 pages), while the list of publications can be pretty long. You usually mention some publications in the CV (well, if you have an article in Science, you surely do!), but surely not all of them.

The list of publications is valuable for different reasons: How many collaborators does he have? How many solo publications? What is the variety of topics? etc. CVs and motivation letters are easy-to-manipulate things. You can manipulate your publications, but that is something completely different (and soft-of more dangerous IMHO).

Comment: Unless this varies hugely by region, I think you're just wrong here about math (which from your user page is your field).  A 2 page CV on a job application in math would be highly highly unusual in the US.

Comment: @NoahSnyder Maybe the habits differ in what goes where (CV, motivation letter, ...). Still, you rarely make a long "shopping list" of your publications in the CV.

Comment: Every CV I've seen from someone applying for a math job has had their full list of publications.  (That said I haven't seen many applications from senior established candidates, so it's possible that they are more abbreviated.)

Comment: "CV should be short (never more than 2 pages)," This is dead wrong for US cvs: rather they are expected to be comprehensive documents.  See e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curriculum_vitae for more explanation on cultural differences.  I would expect to see a full publication list on a CV.  In my field -- mathematics -- people who are not very senior rarely have more than 40 or so publications.  I'm not sure what people who have hundreds of publications do; that's an unusual situation.